# Where can I learn the usage of JNI functions?

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

I am working on an Android project using C++ for the main development and I am trying to implement OpenFeint. I need to call several non-static Java methods and instantiate a couple of classes in my C++ code, and for that I need to learn how to properly use JNI functions.

Where can I find some comprehensive documentation or tutorial on the matter? What I have found so far in Sun's site is incomplete or lackluster, and does not even have the class-method reference.

Comment: You can take the help of below link :-
http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/96.html

Comment: That example is the other way around. I want to call java code from c++, the example calls c++ code from java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have always found the [JNI Programmer's guide](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/download/jni.pdf) to be very useful.
Other than that if you post your questions more  directly am sure SO will help.
And specifically this [section](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/functions.html#70415) might help

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how much of it applies to android, but the official jni specification is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/jniTOC.html). The members of jniEnv are listed as c functions, in c++ the first parameter (jniEnv) falls away.

Answer (score 1):

IBM has an excellent [step by step tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-jni/) for JNI
After you cover it you will feel confident in utilizing JNI.

Besides that I also recommend [JNI tutorial on Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vmRUqajLIuM&feature=related)

Answer (score 0):

Is this any good?

[Calling Java methods from C/C++](http://www.inonit.com/cygwin/jni/invocationApi/c.html)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is not much good documentation about the JNI.

But you can have a look [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/jniTOC.html).
What you need is maybe [creation](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/invoke.html) and of course [invocation](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/fldmeth.html#26254).

Comment: That is the lackluster doc I was talking about. The definition of the methods for JNIEnv is not there, which is PRIMORDIAL for anyone to understand how it works.

Comment: @EfEs: You should have posted this. And AFAIK this is the best you will get. Sorry for this. But what do mean by _definition of the methods_? If you are more specific I am sure you will get help on SO.

Comment: I mean a javadoc style single page with all available methods. The definition for all of them is scattered through the web and loosely defined in text snippets like "You can use Call<Type>Method family of functions to invoke interface methods as well."